# How could i make this view like this in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNDBG.png)

i still confused using component view in jetpack compose,
please help me for making this one. thanks

i was tried but it's not like current view in figma

Comment: Please try to show your effort first then ask others for direct solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Card(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
    .wrapContentHeight(), elevation = 8.dp,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_points_star_icon), modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
            .size(60.dp), contentDescription = "")

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(vertical = 8.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
            Text(text = "Heading Text", style = AppTheme.typography.boldHeaderStyle)
            Text(text = "This is sample body text", color = textColor.copy(0.4f), style = AppTheme.typography.captionTextStyle)
        }
        Button(
            onClick = { /*Your on Click*/ },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
            elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
                defaultElevation = 0.dp,
                pressedElevation = 0.dp,
                disabledElevation = 0.dp,
                hoveredElevation = 0.dp,
                focusedElevation = 0.dp,
            ),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = BackArrowTint.copy(0.6f),
                contentColor = Color.White
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Buy Ticket",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 2.dp, horizontal = 4.dp),
                color = White,
                style = AppTheme.typography.buttonStyle,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Image:
[image]

Comment: You are Welcome! Feel free to ask for any kind of modification or help